# Is mechanically switching SATA drive signals possible?

Tags: switching, hard-drive, sata

Since SATA has made it possible to do all data interfacing to a drive through 4 wires, what I'd like to do is physically route two SATA ports to two drives, through a switch that simply swaps them. This way (for example) the one I want to boot from becomes SATA-0 and the other becomes SATA-1.

For background, many times I've wanted to be able to boot from one of two hard drives on a desktop PC, WHILE keeping both drives accessible to whichever drive I boot from. Often the purpose is to have a choice of operating systems, and to have all the time I need to migrate from one OS to another, while always having the data on both drives available.  I'm fully aware of many dual boot schemes available in some system bios, and of course I know i can always open up my machine and manually swap SATA cables. There are all kinds of solutions other than what I'm asking about, but for now I want to explore this purely electrical/mechanical drive swapping idea.

I realize that swapping two SATA drives would take an 8PDT switch, which might be hard to come by, but I could do it with two 4PDT switches ganged together mechanically, or I could do it with several miniature signal relays, such as those made by OMRON. It certainly would be a universal solution, unbounded by bios limitations and a lot less prone to software "Murphy" problems. But my critical concern that has made me hesitate in designing such a mechanism is that the signals going over an SATA wire are pretty damn fast (I think 5-6 gigabit,a according to wikapedia.

How can I implement an electrical circuit to switch between two SATA ports?

Comment: Theoretically it should be possible. I suspect it would be economically infeasible, though. Do they make relays that are coaxial all the way through?

Comment: I'm assuming that you would want to do the switch when the system was off? Another option would be to use removable drive bays and just switch the drives around.

Comment: you would need controlled impedance tracks, connector, switches, this isn't audio

Comment: drive assignments aren't based on wiring anymore; all the boot selection happens in bios w/o moving parts. that said, you can kill the power to the one you don't want to use for a given session, and it won't autodetect on power-up...

Comment: @Tony Stewart. - I understand about the controlled impedance tracks. Ethernet switches aren't audio either. What is not clear is whether the impact of small relays or mechanical switches would be insignificant enough to make such a thing work.

Comment: @Felthry I was thinking I'd use some of these small OMRON relays. They are rated for 8Ghz, and presumably I could "can" them.  https://www.omron.com/ecb/products/pry/111/g5v_1.html   Since they are DPDT, I'd only need 4 of them. Once the PC layout is done, add a switch to control them all, I can't imagine the entire project being that expensive.

Comment: Where do you see that they are rated for 8GHz? The datasheet doesn't seem to specify past 100MHz...

Comment: While mechanically switching is not appropriate, mostly for SI reasons, there are numerous electronic SATA/SAS switches (typically redrivers, as well). For example, [MAX4986](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX4986.pdf). However, I second dandavis' suggestion of controlling power, rather than trying to mux the data lines.

Comment: It is possible to do this mechanically, it's called hot swapping.

Comment: @ uint128_t I would like to point out that controlling power would not allow both drives to be available after boot. But also, my apologies...I linked the wrong relay. This one is actually rated for 8 Ghz...

https://www.omron.com/ecb/products/pry/113/g6k_2f_rf_v.html

Comment: To whoever down-voted my question, in my opinion you are clueless as to the spirit and intent of this forum. Considering the literal 100+ times I've seen such a question and request for such functionality asked online, its clearly something some people would like to have available, and I am addressing it from a purely engineering vantage point.

Comment: @Randy you specifically asked for an opinion, the moderation system has a button to close opinion based questions. A better question would be to do some research and ask a question like "How could I implement a circuit to switch a sata port?"

Comment: @laptop2d _ I actually do appreciate the edit, as I know I tend to ramble. Not sure I understand why requesting opinions is an issue, but I'll go and read up on the reasoning for it. In any case, I do think the question and answers posted will be useful to others, because it is a search for a solution many would appreciate, and I know I learned a lot from the answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With a mechanical switch or relay? No, that will absolutely not work.

[image: internals of a SATA cable, from Wikipedia]

Here's what a SATA cable looks like internally. The shiny bare wires at the top and bottom, and in the middle, are drain (ground) wires; the copper wires in between those are what carry the signal. As you can see in the picture, they're embedded in a dielectric material. This is to maintain a consistent impedance, which is critical for signal integrity at 6 Gbit/sec.

Bringing those signal wires out of the cable to a mechanical switch will ruin the electrical properties of the connection, and is likely to either prevent the drive from being identified at all, or cause a large number of link errors. If you need to switch a SATA signal, you will need to use an IC specifically designed for this task.

Comment: even -1dB/octave  @ 100MHz from the slope would be enough to cause ISI and signal corruption on signals at 50Mb/s rates.

Comment: Thanks.@duskwuff. As you can probably tell, I'd like to try this even if beating the odds is unlikely. What about relays? I linked the wrong OMRON relay in my previous comment, but this one is actually rated for 8Ghz. Now with relays like that, would you agree in principal that a correctly done PC layout would have a chance? Perhaps to better mimic an SATA cable, I'd use a 4 layer board of a thickness that that would allow for two ground (or in this case shield) planes. 

https://www.omron.com/ecb/products/pry/113/g6k_2f_rf_v.html

Comment: @ Tony Stewart. EE since '75 -- understood. But as you know, sometimes there are tricks we can use to make a "slightly" less than perfect "transmission line" behave better. Consider, for example, in the early days of working with DRAM chips, getting the RAS and CAS strobes to carry and remain synchronized through less than ideal PC runs. The simple addition of some low value damping resistors often worked wonders. I'm not minimizing the opportunities for failure, but in addition to pointing out the many ways this could go wrong, any suggestions toward success would be welcome too! ;-)

Comment: @Randy In principle? Maybe. But those relays cost $50-60 each, and you'd need two of them for a single SATA link…

Comment: @duskwuff - Good point. I'd need 4 of those to do a complete swap, and that would be a pricey experiment, not to mention cutting the PC board. Perhaps the special purpose IC is the only practical solution. I believe @– uint128_t recommended MAX4986 as a possible choice.